# Gitlab-CI does not checkout to latest commit

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I decided to try the gitlab pipeline and made a very simple .gitlab.ci file. Manual launch of the project build and creation of an artifact.

```
---
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
variables:
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: obj
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: ".nuget"
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH: "*/*/"
cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
  - "$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json"
  - "$SOURCE_CODE_PATH$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*"
  - "$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY"
  policy: pull-push
before_script:
- dotnet restore --packages $NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY
build:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  only:
  - web
  script:
  - dotnet build --no-restore
tests:
  stage: test
  when: manual
  only:
  - web
  script:
  - dotnet test --no-restore
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  only:
  - web
  script:
  - dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release
  environment: production
  artifacts:
    name: asd
    paths:
    - asd/bin/asd/
    expire_in: 1 hour
    public: false
```

I manually launched the pipeline and the job I needed. It works well, there are no problems in the job itself. But every time I restart the job, it continues to use the commit with which I started the pipeline the first time. In other words, it does not checkout to the latest commit, but uses the commit at the time the pipeline was created.

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/asd/asd/asd/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 118e10e2 as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
```

I want to have one pipeline with the desired job, which uses the latest commit on every restart. Is it possible to somehow configure it?

I understand that it is possible to add a git command to do poll in the job itself. But I want to achieve such logic with the standard functions of gitlab.ci, so that when the scripts are launched, the repository is up to date.

I can solve this problem every time by creating a new pipeline. Then it will use the latest commit. But I want to achieve this within one pipeline and restart one job.

Comment: Even you may define that gitlab yaml file quote _"very simple"_, for the bonus of the benefit of trouble-shooting but especially for asking about it on Stackoverflow, please reduce it to the minimal version that only contains what provokes the error or unexpected behaviour your want to ask about. Compare [mre].

Comment: And it looks like all of those jobs are manual but your question does not show the commands to execute or restart. Restart is also leaning towards the fact that an existing job (at an existing, single revision) is only re-executed and not that the job is executed at a different revision. Please elaborate on how you execute the job (play the job) and how you select the revision for each of such executions (plays).